Run decorators based on a runtime condition
I have this class:
class A {
  @Transformer()
  prop1: string
}

And I have this decorator:
function Transformer(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  return () => {
    console.log("ran");
  }
}

Normally, in TypeScript, decorators run at build time.
So when I run this code I'll see this in the terminal
"ran!"

I want to only run the functionality inside the decorator when I want by using a function like this:
runTransformations(classInstance);

full-view:
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer'

function Transformer(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  return () => {
    console.log("ran");
  }
}

class A {
  @Transformer()
  prop1: string
}

const classInstance = plainToInstance(A, { prop1: "hello world" })
runTransformations(classInstance);

This is of course possible, because the package class-transformer is able to do that, they're able to make the decorator functionality execute based on a condition, for example look at this:
@Expose({ name: "changedName", onClassOnly: false, onPlainOnly: true })
someProp: string

The above example will only apply the effect when the method instanceToPlain is called, and all of this happens on the runtime.
I want to be able to do the same, I want this code to work as I expect
const classInstance = plainToInstance(A, { prop1: "hello world" })
runTransformations(classInstance);

I want to create a function called runTransformations but I don't know where to start

Can I ask what is the point of using decorators if you want to transform instances? Your runTransformations function is a transformer, just like decorators - they are nothing else than glorifed transformers. What is the benefit of using a decorator if you don't it to be applied?

@EricMORAND. because I have a class that I want to write once, and I want the consumer of my module to use this class without spoiling it with my transformations. If I had to write two classes it would be a cumbersome task, because I have 18 classes, and they're big not small. I need to consume the same class in my module, but in a different way that my module user would want to use it

extending the class of course is an option, but it is no different to creating a new class. Because I almost @transform all the properties on the class, so if I want to override all the properties, I will have to rewrite the property name + the type + other decorators that I want them to always run
